How have philosophers explained the possibility of many minds?
Thinking about the problem of many consciousnesses (if that is the correct term) and searching for the correct terminology, I encountered related concepts, the problem of other minds and solipsism. Much of the problem discussed in those webpages involves the boundary of reality. However, say I don't want to challenge the existence of reality, I am happy to accept that the world which I immediately interact with is real, and that other people exist and feel the same as I do. I wonder instead what philosophers have concluded are implications if indeed there are many minds. For instance, I see myself as the center of a universe (my universe in my mind, at least). If I do not challenge that others are in a similar situation (for instance do not assume that my brain is in a vat and you are simulacra), what does this imply about our joint universe? How have philosophers explained the possibility of many centers (consciousnesses)? Is there some deep implication?

@JoWehler Without dwelling into the related question, my question is not about zombies. The point is that it is easier to imagine the world as my brain in a vat with someone outside the vat in charge. It is harder to see others as equivalent "center of the universes". What are the implications of many minds? You, Jo Wehler, in your room, are you the center of the Universe? No! I am.

You might call this the "multiple perspectives" problem.

I agree with the notation "multiple perspectives". The world-model of each human is centered around their respective self-model. I assume that's a helpful algorithm developed by the biological evolution and implemented into the mind of each individual. - Where is the philosophical problem when different persons have different viewpoints - as long as all are aware that viewpoints are relative positions?

@JoWehler I assume since you are a philosopher and don't see a problem that there isn't one. But (1) I am sure not to be the only one struck by how odd this is, even if selection, neurophysilogy and psychology provide partial mechanistic justifications or explanations; and (2) a philosopher would be deeply curious as to what it is to be one mind, and what it means if there are many. Of course, there are physical implications: can a mind be isolated and transported? Are brain transplants a possibility? Can multiple minds be fused together? Which mind "wins"? Or will they behave as "twins"?

For instance, did Daniel Dennett say anything about this? There are "multiple or split personality" disorders. What about multiple minds in one brain?

Your post and comments ask a series of questions. Unfortunately the rules of this blog prompt us to focus always onto only one question per post. What about selecting one question from the whole bunch, searching for an answer from Dennett, and posing one specific question, if Dennet left open some point? – Moreover: Why is the existence of many persons with many brains and many conscious mental processes with much different content a philosophical issue?

@JoWehler Well, I think the questions I posed in comments helped me think better about this. Thanks for the discussion. Yes, I might have to read Dennett and see if I find something regarding this. (maybe also read Mary Shelley) // Perhaps I don't know what is a philosophical issue (I am a scientist). I thought this was the sort of thing philosophers where supposed to help answer. But I suppose it is a practical question. Connect two chimp brains and see what happens? Cut the right part of one brain and place into another?

You might find Derek Parfit's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasons_and_Persons interesting. A large part of the book is about what the boundaries of "me" are. Also in time. In your picture you only focus on the here and now. But also consider thru time. What justification do you have saying you're still the same person as yeaterday? What would happen in a teleportation?

@mudskipper Thanks, that certainly seems relevant. Can a mind be duplicated, or split? What happens if we upload our minds into AIs? Which one wins? One specific fine point is a little different. The point of "experience" (I used the word perspective, Jo Wehler wrote about mind models). How can an experience (existence) not be unique?

Imo that's a typical gobbledygook philosopher's question that unravels and evaporates when you look closely at it, like a ghostly whisp of poisonous swamp gas. -- How do you know some "given" experience is unique? How do you recognize it as unique? Or as not unique? It's like saying "I am I". Ok, so what? :)

@mudskipper Well, it's potentially untestable, if that's what you mean. You can however compare experiences (giving feedback to someone) to see whether they are unique. Say I upload my mind to AI and it's programmed to operate in an environment replicating reality (a nested universe). Will the "real" mind provide an equivalent output to the uploaded one? If the output is equivalent, does that pose an existential challenge to the original mind? Which one is "more real"?

Strictly speaking, it's not so much a "problem" because it is the intuitive perspective. Philosophical problems tend to arise when they challenge the intuitive perspective. Solipsism, for instance, challenges the view that other minds exist by drawing to the fore the fact we do not have access to other minds in the same introspective way we have of our own.

"...it is easier to imagine the world as my brain in a vat with someone outside the vat in charge..." You need to redefine "world" to be more all-encompassing. Then you would see that you are just adding adding complexity without explaining anything.
